# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp: lookup ”localhost”: no such host

Tags: go-ethereum, error

I'm trying to run a Node on a private blockchain using the following command:

```
geth --datadir data/privateBlockchain/ -networkid 1234567 -port 30306 -nodiscover -rpc -rpcapi “db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug” -rpccorsdomain ”*” --rpcaddr ”localhost” -rpcport 8545
```

I got it from this tutorial:

https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-land-marketplace-dapp-tutorial-part-1-create-and-deploy-a-smart-contract-351bc0d62be2

but when I ran it the following message is shown on the screen:

`Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen tcp: lookup ”localhost”: no such host`

I've also tried with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Change quotes around localhost from smart quotes to "localhost".It worked for me..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't answer why you're getting this specific error, what I can tell you is that specifying `--rcpaddr localhost` is unnecessary as localhost is the default `rpcaddr` value.

If I were to take a swing at guessing *why* you're getting this error though, I would assume that you're quotes around `localhost` are smart quotes, and not the standard kind (they show up that way on this site, at least). If you really want to explicitly set the RPC bind address to `localhost` (explicit is better than implicit, to some) try removing the quotes!

Comment: It was an issue with the quotes as you said! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, cheers!